# SQL fuzzy search

Tags: java, sql, fuzzy-search

I have to call SQL database search in my Java program.

The retrieving condition is that user input string partially matches NAME filed and not case sensitive. For example, if user input "joe", students' records with name like "Joea", "Bjoe","JOEED" should be returned.

While I tried to write code as bellow. It doesn't seem to be able to work out.

Can someone tell me why? Thanks.

```
String fuzzySearch = "UPPER(%" + inputStr + "%)";
String query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE UPPER(student.name) LIKE ? ";
PreparedStatement prepStatement = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
prepStatement.setObject(1,fuzzySearch);
```

Comment: What on earth does "It doesn't seem to be able to work out." mean? It throws an error? If so, what's the error? It doesn't return the expected results? If not, what *is* it returning?

Comment: http://gordonlesti.com/fuzzy-fulltext-search-with-mysql/ Even though it is php, you can easily translate that into java. The important part was that it uses mysql which seems to be important in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using a string bind variable, you are saying

```
WHERE UPPER(student.name) LIKE 'UPPER(%joe%)'
```

instead of

```
WHERE UPPER(student.name) LIKE UPPER('%joe%')
```

So use

```
String fuzzySearch = "%" + inputStr + "%";
String query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE UPPER(student.name) LIKE UPPER(?) ";
PreparedStatement prepStatement = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
prepStatement.setObject(1,fuzzySearch);
```

instead.